# Syntax Error inside an if function inside a loop

Tags: python

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to create a new function, inside which I want to update a variable "pas" whenever I run this function. 
Why do i get this error?

I've tried using a int(), str(), with the value (1) and changing the += to 
pas = pas + 1 
Checking the indent

```
for i in range(abs(dy)-1):
    if board[(d_board[active_figure[0]]+i)][d_board[active_figure[1]] == '  ':
        pas += 1
        if pas == i:
            moving()
    else:
        print ('Error: The path is blocked[272]')
        move_ai()
```

Comment: You have one missing `']'`.

Comment: What is `this error`? Can you show it?

Comment: Please include your full code for us to understand what is going on!

Comment: `if board[(d_board[active_figure[0]]+i)][d_board[active_figure[1]] == '  ':`misses a square bracket: `if board[(d_board[active_figure[0]]+i)][d_board[active_figure[1]]] == '  ':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : You should try and update this question by giving the error thrown to you and providing more code snippet regarding to this function.

Now, as per the code provided right now, you are missing a "]" where you are checking for a blank.
Also if you are checking for a blank, should not give blank spaces.

This is all can be understood by your provided question and code snippet try these changes and update.

try this :

```
for i in range(abs(dy)-1):
if board[(d_board[active_figure[0]]+i)][d_board[active_figure[1]]] == '':
    pas += 1
    if pas == i:
        moving()
else:
    print ('Error: The path is blocked[272]')
    move_ai()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a place with two spaces that's fine, i tried to add a ] and it worked perfectly, should get more fresh brain next time, but much thanks anyway